# Production Environment Works Fine, Local Development Breaks: Fetch Issues Causing Page Breakage

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

My application functions smoothly in the production environment, however, encounters issues in local development. Recently, I've been troubleshooting fetch-related problems that result in the entire page breaking. Initially, I managed to resolve the issue by deleting cookies, but unexpectedly, the authentication session cookie vanished overnight. It appears that the absence of this particular cookie, which used to cause conflicts, is now impacting functionality. Currently, only two cookies are visible, and the application fails to operate as intended.

This is my [...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'name',

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const payload = {
          rut: credentials.rut,
          password: credentials.password,
        };

        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        const response = await res.json();

        if (!res.ok || response.status == 'fail') {
          throw new Error(response.message);
        }

        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (res.ok && response) {
          return response.data;
        }

        // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null;
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'dashboard',
      name: 'Credenciales Dashboard',

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const payload = {
          email: credentials.email,
          password: credentials.password,
        };

        const res = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/organizations/login`,
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );

        const user = await res.json();

        if (!res.ok || user.status == 'invalid_credentials') {
          throw new Error(user.message);
        }

        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }

        // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null;
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'freemium',

      name: 'name',

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const payload = {
          email: credentials.email,
          password: credentials.password,
        };

        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        const response = await res.json();

        if (!res.ok || response.status == 'fail') {
          throw new Error(response.message);
        }

        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (res.ok && response) {
          return response.data;
        }

        // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null;
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
  },

  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  events: {
    async signOut({ token, session, res }) {
      // Remove the authentication cookies
      res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
        `next-auth.session-token=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`, //Missing cookie 
        `next-auth.csrf-token=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`,
      ]);

      // Clear the token and session
      token = {};
      session = {};
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }) {
      // the user object is what returned from the Credentials login, it has `accessToken` from the server `/login` endpoint
      // assign the accessToken to the `token` object, so it will be available on the `session` callback

      if (trigger === 'update') {
        token.user = session.user;
        return token;
      }

      if (user && user.type != 'linkedin') {
        token.accessToken = user.token;
        token.user = user.user;
        token.organization = user.organization;
        token.subscription_active = user.subscription_active;
      } else if (user && user.type == 'linkedin') {
        const payload = {
          linkedin_id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          image_url: user.image,
        };

        const res = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/login/linkedin`,
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );

        const response = await res.json();
        const data = response.data;

        token.accessToken = data.token;
        token.user_info = data.user;
        token.board = data.board;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, trigger }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      session.user.accessTokenExpires = token.accessTokenExpires;

      if (token) {
        // const res = await fetch(
        //  `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/profile?token=${token.accessToken}`
        // );
        // const response = await res.json(res);
        session.user = token.user;
        session.organization = token.organization;
        session.subscription_active = token.subscription_active;
        session.board = token.board;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  // Enable debug messages in the console if you are having problems
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});
```

I have attempted to tackle the issue from various angles. I've tried deleting the visible cookies, uninstalling and reinstalling the nodemodules and the .next directory, as well as tweaking the Next.js configuration. Moreover, I've double-checked the environment variables to ensure they are correctly set up. Despite these efforts, the problem persists, and the page continues to malfunction in the local environment.